# why use 'ref' when you use useCallback instead of using useCallback directly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-usecallback

I'm working on React project, and I was investigating some libraries. and I found they used 'useCallback" differently from what I've used.
Below is that code part. I still think this code has no difference from using "useCallback" in a direct way though

```
// Saves incoming handler to the ref in order to avoid "useCallback hell"
export function useEventCallback<T, K>(handler?: (value: T, event: K) => void): (value: T, event: K) => void {
  const callbackRef = useRef(handler);

  useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = handler;
  });

  return useCallback((value: T, event: K) => callbackRef.current && callbackRef.current(value, event), []);
}
```

so my question is that what does mean by 'useCallback hell'? and what is the advantage of using "useCallback" such that way?

// BTW : I found a similar example on react documentation. but I still couldn't understand
https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-read-an-often-changing-value-from-usecallback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do a normal `useCallback`, you must pass in a dependency array containing the variables your function uses. When one of them changes, the memoization breaks. This is fine in many cases, but sometimes your memoization is breaking all the time (because you depend on values that change all the time). When this happens, `useCallback` provides little or no benefit.

The code you've shown has the goal that the memoization *never* breaks, even if you have complicated dependencies. Note that when it calls `useCallback`, it passes in an empty dependency array `[]`. That's combined with using a ref to be able to keep track of what the latest `handler` is. Then when the function is eventually called, it will check the ref for the latest `handler` and call it. That latest `handler` has the latest values in its closure, so it behaves as expected.

This code does achieve its goal of never breaking memoization. However, it needs to be used carefully. If you are using react's concurrent rendering, and you call the function returned by `useEventCallback` during rendering, you can get some unexpected results. It's only safe to call the function outside of rendering, such as in an event callback, which is why they named it `useEventCallback`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and Sorry for checking late. I had issue with my account in Stack overflow
By the Way, I have one more question from your answer.
"If you are using react's concurrent rendering, and you call the function returned by useEventCallback during rendering, you can get some unexpected results."
in this sentence I'm curious why it might get unexpected results when it's in concurrent rendering?

Comment: If you created it like so: `const yourCallback = useRef(()=>{})`, and then updated it in `useEffect()` like so: `useEffect(()=>{ yourCallback.current = ()=>{/*stuff*/}; },[dependencies])`, would it be functionally equivalent to `useCallback()`?

Answer (score 2):

Explanations with some examples:

## Function in component body

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const lastRenderTime = new Date().toString();
  
  function bodyFn() {
    alert("bodyFn: " + lastRenderTime);
  }

  return (
    <>
      Last render time: {lastRenderTime}
      <SomeChildComponent onClick={bodyFn} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Whenever the `<App>` component re-renders (e.g. if the `count` state is modified), a new `bodyFn` is created.

Should `<SomeChildComponent>` monitor its `onClick` prop reference (typically in a dependency array),  it will see that new creation everytime.

But the event callback behaviour is as expected: whenever `bodyFn` is called, it is the "most recent creation" of that function, and in particular it correctly uses the latest value of `lastRenderTime` (the same as already displayed).

## Common usage of `useCallback`

```
function App() {
  const lastRenderTime = new Date().toString();
  
  const ucbFn = useCallback(
    () => alert("ucbFn: " + lastRenderTime),
    [lastRenderTime]
  );

  return (
    <>
      Last render time: {lastRenderTime}
      <SomeChildComponent onClick={ucbFn} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Whenever the `<App>` re-renders, the `lastRenderTime` value is different. Hence the `useCallback` dependency array kicks in, creating a new updated function for `ucbFn`.

As in the previous case, `<SomeChildComponent>` will see that change everytime. And the usage of `useCallback` seems pointless!

But at least, the behaviour is also as expected: the function is always up-to-date, and shows the correct `lastRenderTime` value.

## Attempt to avoid `useCallback` dependency

```
function App() {
  const lastRenderTime = new Date().toString();
  
  const ucbFnNoDeps = useCallback(
    () => alert("ucbFnNoDeps: " + lastRenderTime),
    [] // Attempt to avoid cb modification by emptying the dependency array
  );

  return (
    <>
      Last render time: {lastRenderTime}
      <SomeChildComponent onClick={ucbFnNoDeps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

In a "naive" attempt to restore the advantage of `useCallback`, one may be tempted to remove `lastRenderTime` from its dependency array.

Now `ucbFnNoDeps` is indeed always the same, and `<SomeChildComponent>` will see no change.

But now, the behaviour is no longer as one could expect: `ucbFnNoDeps` reads the value of `lastRenderTime` *that was in its scope when it was created*, i.e. the **first** time `<App>` was rendered!

## With custom `useEventCallback` hook

```
function App() {
  const lastRenderTime = new Date().toString();
  
  const uecbFn = useEventCallback(
    () => alert("uecbFn: " + lastRenderTime),
  );

  return (
    <>
      Last render time: {lastRenderTime}
      <SomeChildComponent onClick={uecbFn} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Whenever the `<App>` re-renders, a new arrow function (argument of `useEventCallback` custom hook) is created. But the hook internally just stores it in its `useRef` current placeholder.

The hook returned function, in `uecbFn`,  never changes. So `<SomeChildComponent>` sees no change.

But the initially expected behaviour is restored: when the callback is executed, it will look for the current placeholder content, which is the most recently created arrow function. Which therefore uses the most recent `lastRenderTime` value!

### Example of `<SomeChildComponent>`

An example of a component that depends on the reference of one of its callback props could be:

```
function SomeChildComponent({
  onClick,
}: {
  onClick: () => void;
}) {
  const countRef = useRef(0);
  
  useEffect(
    () => { countRef.current += 1; },
    [onClick] // Increment count when onClick reference changes
  );
  
  return (
    <div>
      onClick changed {countRef.current} time(s)
      <button onClick={onClick}>click</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Demo on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dubinsky-qjp3gk

Comment: Thank you for your kind and detailed explanation. It helped me a lot. and I understood almost everything.
and sorry for comment late, I had issue with my account in stackoverflow.